in typescript, how to write a generic function that returns the typeof
Here is my TypeScript code:
interface TheType{
  name:string
}
function get_ts_type<T>(): string {
  return // todo: implement this
}
function test_it(){
  const ans=get_ts_type<TheType>()
  console.log(ans) //should print TheType
}
test_it()

My question is: is it at all posible to implement get_ts_type so it returns TheType in the test program above ?
Edit: here is my use case, its to work with the very ellborate type system of acorn
export function cast<T extends Node>(node:Node):T|null{
  const typestring=get_ts_type<T>()
  if (node.type == typestring)
    return node as T
  return null
}    
function process_node(elem:Node){
  const fdecl=cast<FunctionDeclaration>(elem)
  if (fdecl){
    const field_name=fdecl.id.name
    console.log(field_name)
  }
}

edit: this is not a duplicate because the question doent talk about checking in runine, its more about type guards and generics

Interfaces don't exist at runtime, so I doubt this is possible as written in the question.

Not only can you not do this, it isn't at clear why you'd want to: the whole point of interfaces is that they can be implemented by many concrete types, having a function that said "this thing is an interface" at runtime seems like a bit of an odd thing to want? When OO lore says instanceof is a code smell, that's the kind of thing they're talking about.

@JaredSmith i just added a use case

TL;DR Just use a user-defined type guard.

it does not answer the the question because i'll have to write a function per type and there are many many  types in acorn. its a shame that the question was closed so quickly -its not realy a duplicate. maybe someone out would come up with an easier to user solution

@Jared Smith i now get, thanks. for my use case i have cerated many type guards using a script that parses out the acord.d.ts
